# removing nested html tags using HTMLPurifier or regexp

Tags: php, html, regex

I am searching for a way to get rid of some nested html tags and already spend some time searching for the correct way to do so.
As I am already using HTML Purifier I would like to find a way using it, but also knowing about other possible solutions (e.g. the correct way of using regexp's in PHP) would be great :)

This is an example of the HTML-Structure I have:

```
<p><span><span>SOME TEXT</span></span></p>
<table><tbody><tr>
<td><span><span>SOME TEXT</span></span><span>SOME MORE TEXT</span></td>
<td><div><span><span>SOME TEXT</span></span></div><div><span>SOME MORE TEXT</span></div></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
<p>SOME TEXT</p>
```

I would like to get this output :

```
<p><span><span>SOME TEXT</span></span></p>
<table><tbody><tr>
<td>SOME TEXT SOME MORE TEXT</td>
<td>SOME TEXT SOME MORE TEXT</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
<p>SOME TEXT</p>
```

So what I basically want is a way to remove all div and span tags that are nested in a td tag and only then.

Is there a way of achieving this using HTML Purifier or does somebody know another way of getting this result?
(I already checked the HTML Purifier Documentation but could not find a way to remove only the nested tags)

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Don't use regexp.  Regexp can't parse HTML and you will go mad in the attempt.

Comment: html doesn't seem to follow nesting too well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3897316

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. Can you maybe think of a good tool to use to achieve this output?Unfortunately I can not change the Input.I would like to use a tool like HTlML Purfier, but it does not seem to support this usecase.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no choice then your best bet is to pre-process the text replacing open/close tags with single characters.
This makes the changes easier to perform and your pre-processing can be unrolled fairly painlessly (excuse the code I've not done any php for a couple of years):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\&/', '&amp;', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\@/', '&at;', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\#/', '&hash;', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\<td/', '@', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\<\/td/', '#', $str);

while preg_match('/(\@[^\#]*)<[\/]?span[^\>]*>/', $str) {
    $str = preg_replace('/(\@[^\#]*)<[\/]?span[^\>]*>/', '$1', $str);
}

$str = preg_replace('/\@/', '<td', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\#/', '</td', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\&hash;/', '#', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\&at;/',   '@', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\&amp;/',  '&', $str);
```

I've something similar in JS to clean HTML, hope this helps.